# Composition of Transpositions Proof

Tags: permutations

Here is the question that I'm working on:

> Show that if $n \geq 2$, then every permutation of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ can be expressed as the composition of transpositions of the form ($1$ $a$), where $a = 2,3,...,n$.

We'll, let's say that we call such a set $S$ such that it has the elements $$S = \{1,2,3\}.$$

Then it's obvious that the composition of transpositions for this set if given by $$(13),(12)$$

That's the case only when $n = 3$ and $a = 2,3$. Visually, I know that this result will happen for other values of $n$ and $a$, but describing this observation as a proof is where I'm stuck on. How should I start the proof?

**EDIT** It seems the way to handle this problem is to give a proof by induction on $n$.

Comment: Any permutation on all $n$ elements can be written as $(1, a, b, \ldots c, d, n) = (1, n)(1, d)(1, c) \ldots (1, b)(1, a)$.

Comment: Ah yes I believe I saw a proof of this on my textbook. But that's all there is to it?

Comment: @BenjaminDickman: What you have shown is any cycle  can be expressed so. You need to add a remark to make it complete.

Comment: What type of remark should he add?